# Autoscaling of GCP VM Instances and its relation with machine-type

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have dataflow jobs which are running on gcp instances . There are 2 instances one is master and other is worker .
The machine type of worker is n1-standard-8.

At normal time , job runs successfully but at times the data size is  huge when our jobs fail with below issue:

```
The job failed because a work item has failed 4 times. Look in previous log entries for the cause of each one of the 4 failures. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors. The work item was attempted on these workers: 
  job-20190-04240315-izqn-harness-cfj8,

  job-20190-04240315-izqn-harness-cfj8,

  job-20190-04240315-izqn-harness-cfj8,

  job-20190-04240315-izqn-harness-cfj8
```

As per  the understanding it is heap issue , so increased the machine type to n1-standard-16. The job ran successfully.

Need to understand that how autoscaling did not worked in this case and increasing the machine type worked.

How Auoscaling and increasing the machine-type related or worked.

Comment: Include the Stackdriver logs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the autoscaling only works for the number of workers, not changing the machine type. Related document is [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#autoscaling).

Comment: Neither of them is working with 1.5 million of data . Raised a concern to GCP teams